# command execution in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to execute the following command, it works perfectly, if I execute it via command prompt, here the command line is using kodakprv.exe to send a print of a tiff file.

but when trying to execute it via c#, its not throwing any error but not sending the print either, tried to execute this command via xp_cmdshell in SQL, but it didn't work, in the xp_cmdshell documentation found that, quotes are not allowed for more then once, but kodakprv.exe print logic requires 3 pair of quotes

Please suggest can we use multiple quotes in C# while executing the command or suggest any better solution for it

```
String sCommand = "\"c:\\progra~1\\imagin~1\\kodakprv.Exe\" /pt \"D:\\SQLDev\\Dlls\\Testing.TIF\" \"\\\\Galactica\\C-Test1\"";
// Put your code here

System.Diagnostics.Process ExecuteCommand = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    startInfo.Arguments = @" /c " + sCommand.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(startInfo.Arguments);
    ExecuteCommand.StartInfo = startInfo;
    ExecuteCommand.Start();
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Do you get an exception? How does it not behave as you expect?

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem description. Explain what you expect to happen, what does happen and what you have tried to resolve those differences.

Comment: Yes u right, actually this command is supposed to send a print, here I am using kodakprv.exe to send a print of tiff file.

Here I do not get any exception or error, its just that the command executes without sending the print, where as If I execute this command on normal command prompt, it works perfectly.

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried to execute the same command via xp_cmdshell in SQL, but that does not work either, what I see in xp_cmdshell documentation is that it does not allow the quotes more then once, where as I need here three pair of quotes, as required by the kodakprv.exe command line, that is why I tried C# code, if it would work will use it as a CLR in SQL, but for now the same command isn't working in C# either, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those quotes. Only paths with spaces require quotes. None of your paths have spaces.

Shortnames, as you are using, may not exist (they can be turned off), or may not have the name you think. Windows does not preserve short names, only long names.

You are running your program via CMD. Unless your command line has redirection characters (as CMD handles redirection characters) then CMD is not required. You can start your program directly, which would be the preferred way (faster, less resources used).

Your window is set to hidden. Therefore you cannot see the message it is telling you. Unhide your window.

Your program will likely exit and close the window before you can read it. Either stick a `&pause` at the end of the command line sent to CMD, or read what is on both StdErr and StdOut as you specify to capture them in your code.

Comment: thanks for your reply @serenity, I tried to use Kodakprv.exe directly and it worked fine, where as still I can't use the same code in CLR, it seems like interactive with desktop feature is restricting it, any suggestions on it.